# Javascript to set hidden form value on drop down change

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to javascript, but I'm sure this is easy.  Unfortunately, most of the google results haven't been helpful.

Anyway, I want to set the value of a hidden form element through javascript when a drop down selection changes.

I can use jQuery, if it makes it simpler to get or set the values.

Comment: the "new answers have been posted" seemed to have failed on us all, lol

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you have HTML like this, for example:

```
<select id='myselect'>
    <option value='1'>A</option>
    <option value='2'>B</option>
    <option value='3'>C</option>
    <option value='4'>D</option>
</select>
<input type='hidden' id='myhidden' value=''>
```

All you have to do is [bind a function to the `change` event of the select](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change#fn), and do what you need there:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function() {
    $('#myselect').change(function() {
        // if changed to, for example, the last option, then
        // $(this).find('option:selected').text() == D
        // $(this).val() == 4
        // get whatever value you want into a variable
        var x = $(this).val();
        // and update the hidden input's value
        $('#myhidden').val(x);
    });
});
</script>
```

All things considered, if you're going to be doing a lot of jQuery programming, always have the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) open. It is very easy to find what you need there if you give it a chance.

Answer (score 10):

Plain old Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function changeHiddenInput (objDropDown)
{
    var objHidden = document.getElementById("hiddenInput");
    objHidden.value = objDropDown.value; 
}

</script>
<form>
    <select id="dropdown" name="dropdown" onchange="changeHiddenInput(this)">
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="hiddenInput" id="hiddenInput" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: I'm new to the game - will `onchange` be allowed by the content security policy?

Answer (score 8):

I'd fought with this a long time `$('#myelement').val(x)` just wasn't working ... until I realized the `#` construction requires an ID, not a NAME.  So if "`.val(x)` doesn't work!" is your problem, check your element and be sure it has an ID!

It's an embarrassing gotcha, but I felt I had to share to save others much hair-tearing.

Comment: Whoops...Just had the same issue!

Answer (score 3):

Here you can set hidden's value at onchange event of dropdown list :

```
$('#myDropDown').bind('change', function () {
  $('#myHidden').val('setted value');
});
```

your hidden and drop down list :

```
<input type="hidden" id="myHidden" />

<select id="myDropDown">
   <option value="opt 1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="opt 2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="opt 3">Option 3</option>
</ select>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is with jQuery.

```
$('#selectFormElement').change( function() {
    $('#hiddenFormElement').val('newValue');
} );
```

**In the html**

```
<select id="selectFormElement" name="..."> ... </select>
<input type="hidden" name="..." id="hiddenFormElement" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to be different, changed my answer so that this question doesn't have 5 answers with the same code.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Page</title>  
   <script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
   <script>
       $(function() {
           var select = $("body").append('<form></form>').children('form')
                .append('<input type="hidden" value="" />').children('input[type=hidden]')
                .attr('id', 'hiddenValue').end()
                .append('<select></select>').children('select')
                .attr('id', 'dropdown')
                .change(function() {
                    alert($(this).val());
                });

           $.each({ one: 1, two: 2, three: 3, four: 4, five: 5 }, function(txt, val) {
               select.append('<option value="' + val + '">' + txt + '</option>');
           });
       });
</script>
</head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="selval">
  <select onchange="this.form.selval.value=this.selectedIndex">
    <option>val1</option>
    <option>val2</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

pure javascript from within a form

Comment: I was under the impression that using "this.form.elementName" was deprecated in favour of "document.getElementById('xx')"
...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
$('#myselect').change(function() {
   $('#myhidden').val =$("#myselect option:selected").text();
    });
});
```