# How to assign dropdown selected value to a hidden field

Tags: asp.net, jquery

i have a dropdownlist  control in asp.net which resides in a user control .The yuser control has a updatepannel .I want to set the dropdown selected value to a hidden field .How will i do this in javascript /Jquery .I don't want to use server code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815687/javascript-to-set-hidden-form-value-on-drop-down-change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery it's pretty straightforward:

```
$('#select_id').bind('change', function(){
   $('#hiddenfield_id').val($(this).val());
});
```

See it in action: http://www.jsfiddle.net/YjC6y/15/

(you would have to change the type from "text" to "hidden")

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much the same as **jAndy**, but adds the server tags to get the ID for the ASP.NET Controls.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#<%= ddlDropDownList.ClientID %>').change(function() {
  $('#<%= htxtHiddenField.ClientID %>').val($(this).val());
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#hiddenFieldID').val( $('#selectMenyID').val() );
```

Or if you want to do it whenever the user changes the menu, do it using [a `.change()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/change/):

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectMenyID').change(function() {
        $('#hiddenFieldID').val( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

You *get* and *set* the value of a form element [with `.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). When you don't give it an argument, you're *getting* the value. When you do, you're *setting* the value.

So a more verbose version of the same thing could look like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#selectMenyID').change(function() {
            // Get the value, and store it in a variable
        var theValue = $(this).val();
            // Set that value to the hidden input
        $('#hiddenFieldID').val( theValue );
    });
});
```

Wrapping your code with `$(function() {...});` is a shortcut for calling [jQuery's `.ready()` method](http://api.jquery.com/ready/), which makes sure the elements are loaded before the code runs.