# Save DropDownList value into a javascript variabale

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, hidden-fields

I am relatively new to C#, and I have been researching this across the internet for a few days now. I need the value selected in asp.net DropDownList to be declared as a JavaScript variable. I have looked into `<asp:hiddenfield>`'s mostly, but I'm not sure if this is the best option to go down. So I have two questions:

1. Are `<asp:hiddenfield>`'s the best option?
2. How do you declare a C# string into a javascript variable?

   ```
   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownID">
       <asp:ListItem Text="-- Select Reason --" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Booking" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Discussing" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Text="Quotation" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>

   <asp:hiddenfield ID="valueInHiddenField" value="" runat="server"/>
   ```

Comment: Have you tried doing something similar to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815687/javascript-to-set-hidden-form-value-on-drop-down-change

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var serverDropdown = document.getElementById('dropDownID');
    var reasonIndex = serverDropdown.selectedIndex;
    var reasonValue = serverDropdown.value;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this `<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownID">` to this:

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownID" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

and then use this JavaScript to get the value:

```
var val = document.getElementById('dropDownID').value;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. That returns - 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null'

Comment: @user883867, what version of ASP.NET are you using?

Answer (score 0):

To store dropdownlist value in javascript variable, there is no need to use hidden field,

try this...

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     var dropdown_value = document.getElementById('<%=dropDownID.ClientID%>').value;
 </script>
```

here instead of dropdownID we have to use its ClientID.....In asp.net 4.0 you can direclty use 
its id by doing ClientIDMode="Static" of the dropdown.

```
     var dropdown_value = document.getElementById('dropDownID').value;
```