# Select and hidden

Tags: javascript, html, select

I have a simple Select with several options. Then i have a hidden input.

I want to valorize that hidden input with the selected option.

so if:

```
    <select id="type" name="type">
        <option value=""><fmt:message key="select.value" bundle="${g}" /></option>
        <option value="0"><fmt:message key="intermediary.document.attachment.logo" bundle="${i}" /></option>
        <option select="selected" value="RISKASSESS"><fmt:message key="intermediary.document.attachment.riskassess" bundle="${i}" /></option>
   </select>
```

I want this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="ADVPF3" />
```

Someone can help me? Thx.

Comment: Valorize? Huh? Do you mean validate?

Comment: If you mean "set the value based on select" , you can have a look at [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815687/javascript-to-set-hidden-form-value-on-drop-down-change)

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do this in plain javascript,

```
var e = document.getElementById("selectId");

e.addEventListener("change",function(){
    //Get selected value
    var val = e.value;
    //Set value to input
    document.getElementById("type").value = val;
});
```

If you have jQuery in place then,

```
$("#selectId").change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   $('#type').val(x);
});
```

Do note that you cannot give the same id (now type) to both select and input