# Pull a variable and category from a forms option select and post it to a hidden input

Tags: javascript, forms, variables, input

I am trying to pass to variable from a form select but I am running into issues.

How do I accomplish sending the catSubcat, value, and more variables. I have tried so many different things.

Update: I have created the jsfiddle below. I kinda have to be vague due to security here.

With the example html you will see category (DA, DC, etc..), multi acct code(M02 or M03 based on the amount), multi name (Bundle). For testing the clients can make up the inputs to do their testing. Once I receive the code from the other department I have to hide all the inputs except the products, but they will populate into a hidden field.

How it is supposed to work: A user goes to the account page and selects however many and whatever account. Based on their selections the category, multi code and multi name will be passed through the submit to another page and submit all the variables.

Not my code and I cannot change it due to the other departments requirements.

```
<https://jsfiddle.net/jm1w6ycv/2/>
```

Comment: Can you precise where is your problem in the code you posted?

Comment: I am unable to pull in the catSubcat from the select option with what I've tried, so I just wanted to ask a general question asking how do I do it. I have tried .val and it does bring an alert that I have set with the value but not the catSubcat.

Comment: Check out [Javascript to set hidden form value on drop down change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815687/javascript-to-set-hidden-form-value-on-drop-down-change)

Comment: Thank you for sending the link above. I have looked at it and have more of an understanding, but I am not sure how to directly use it in the manner i need it. I have updated the OP.